# Plotly is not rendering Choropleth Mapbox Polygons

Tags: python, plotly, geojson, plotly-python

I have been trying to render geoJSON in Plotly by converting shapefiles from https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/local-authority-districts-december-2019-boundaries-uk-bfc.

The Python Plotly docs for `plotly.graph_objects.Choroplethmapbox` mention that in the geoJSON an `id` field is required for each feature. I have tried both creating an artificial `id` and using the plotly `featurekeyid` field but neither of them are working. When I do use the `id` key, I have checked that the `id` key is in the correct location and have tried both as int64 and string.

Sometimes the base mapbox layer will render but no polygons and others the code will run and then hang.

I have also tried reducing the size of the .shp file using mapshaper's various algorithms then saving that to geoJSON format and skipping the conversion step in Python from .shp to geoJSON but again to no avail. Also changing the `tolerance` in the `shapely` manipulation does not seem to change the output.

What I am expecting is a map projection with a mapbox base layer with the local authority district polygons on top and filled. The below link shows the polygons and was created on mapshaper.org:

[Polygons of Local Authority District](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAGMl.png)

My mapbox access token is valid.

This is an example of trying to render the Local Authority Boundaries polygons by adding in an `id` field and converting the .shp file to geoJSON and then creating the trace:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiLineString
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# load in shp files
lad_shp = gpd.read_file('zip://../../data/external/Local_Authority_Districts_(December_2019)_Boundaries_UK_BFC-shp.zip', encoding='utf-8')

# using empet code to convert .shp to geoJSON
def shapefile_to_geojson(gdf, index_list, tolerance=0.025): 
    # gdf - geopandas dataframe containing the geometry column and values to be mapped to a colorscale
    # index_list - a sublist of list(gdf.index)  or gdf.index  for all data
    # tolerance - float parameter to set the Polygon/MultiPolygon degree of simplification
    # returns a geojson type dict 

    geo_names = list(gdf[f'lad19nm']) # name of authorities
    geojson = {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': []}
    for index in index_list:
        geo = gdf['geometry'][index].simplify(tolerance)

        if isinstance(geo.boundary, LineString):
            gtype = 'Polygon'
            bcoords = np.dstack(geo.boundary.coords.xy).tolist()

        elif isinstance(geo.boundary, MultiLineString):
            gtype = 'MultiPolygon'
            bcoords = []
            for b in geo.boundary:
                x, y = b.coords.xy
                coords = np.dstack((x,y)).tolist() 
                bcoords.append(coords) 
        else: pass



        feature = {'type': 'Feature', 
                   'id' : index,
                   'properties': {'name': geo_names[index]},
                   'geometry': {'type': gtype,
                                'coordinates': bcoords},
                    }

        geojson['features'].append(feature)
    return geojson

geojsdata = shapefile_to_geojson(lad_shp, list(lad_shp.index))

# length to generate synthetic data for z attribute
L = len(geojsdata['features'])

# check id key is there
geojsdata['features'][0].keys()
>> dict_keys(['type', 'id', 'properties', 'geometry'])

# example of authroity name
geojsdata['features'][0]['properties']['name']
>> 'Hartlepool'

# check id
k=5
geojsdata['features'][k]['id']
>> '5'

trace = go.Choroplethmapbox(z=np.random.randint(10, 75, size=L),  # synthetic data
                            locations=[geojsdata['features'][k]['id'] for k in range(L)],
                            colorscale='Viridis',
                            colorbar=dict(thickness=20, ticklen=3),
                            geojson=geojsdata,
                            text=regions,
                            marker_line_width=0.1, marker_opacity=0.7)
layout = go.Layout(title_text='UK LAD Choropleth Demo',
                   title_x=0.5,
                   width=750,
                   height=700,
                   mapbox=dict(center=dict(lat=54, lon=-2),
                               accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
                               zoom=3))

fig=go.Figure(data=[trace], layout =layout)
fig.show()
```

The geoJSON output from the above `shapefile_to_geojson` function can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vuf3jtrr2boq5eg/lad19-geo.json?dl=0

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing the issue? I'm assuming the .shp files are good as they are rendered fine on mapshaper.org and QGis. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply changing the projection system corrected the error. Doing this before conversion to geoJSON:

```py
lad_shp = lad_shp.to_crs(epsg=4326)
```